# How to get full height and width of range, including borders?

Tags: vba, excel, size, range

I can't seem to find an answer to this anywhere.

In VBA, given `Dim r As Range: Set r = Range("C20:C21")` I can get `r.height` and `r.width`, where the former is the combined height of cells C20 and C21 but this doesn't include the size of the borders in between them.

Is there a reliable method of obtaining the full combined height and width (e.g.: height and width of cells + size of the borders in between those cells) ?

Thanks.

Comment: To draw a thick line `Range("C20:C21").Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = xlContinuous` & `xlEdgeTop` & `Bottom` for the height and width use  `Range("C20:C21").ColumnWidth = 4` & `Rows("3").RowHeight = 4`

Comment: @Omar Thanks, but I wasn't asking how to draw but how to get the width and height of ranges with the size of the boarders in between cells factored in.

Comment: In a quick test, adding a thick bottom border increased the reported height  of a single cell selection from 15 to 15.75   Maybe you could give some more detail around what the exact problem is?

Comment: What I'm trying to do is create a ComboBox control and place it vertically exactly half way between two cells, like `testCB.Height = 16.5: testCB.Top = testCB.Top + ((r.Height / 2) - (testCB.Height) / 2)` but it ends up slightly off. It seemed that something was throwing off the calculation and I thought it was a border (maybe an outer one?)

Answer (score 0):

I think your calculation should be

```
testCB.Top = testCB.Top + ((r.Height - testCB.Height) / 2))
```

Or rather (not sure what your version even means)

```
testCB.Top = r.Top + ((r.Height - testCB.Height) / 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

This can get the weight of border.

```
'If all borders are equal, you can take the weight as follow:
Range("C20:C21").Borders.Value

'If you want a specific border, you can use as follow:
Range("C20:C21").Borders(xlEdgeLeft).Weight
```

If this is work for you, your calculation will be as follow:

```
height = Range("C20:C21").Height + _
         Range("C20:C21").Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight + _
         Range("C20:C21").Borders(xlEdgeTop).Weight

width = Range("C20:C21").Width + _
        Range("C20:C21").Borders(xlEdgeLeft).Weight + _
        Range("C20:C21").Borders(xlEdgeRight).Weight
```

And If you also want border between two cell for height, you can use as follow:

```
height = Range("C20:C21").Height + _
         Range("C20:C21").Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight + _
         Range("C20:C21").Borders(xlEdgeTop).Weight + _
         Range("C20:C21").Borders(xlInsideVertical).Weight
```